# How can I multiply 2 x 2 matrices of 64 bit integers efficiently using SSE/AVX instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, matrix-multiplication

Is there a way to multiply 2 x 2 matrices of unsigned 64 bit integers using SSE or AVX,

that is more efficient than just using none SSE/AVX instructions?

Comment: How are the matrices represented in RAM?

Comment: Try to write this in C and let your C compiler figure this out.  It was able to generate pretty good code for me.

Comment: The answer may depend on whether you are considering 64b x 64b -> 128b, or whether you only want the bottom 64 bits of the result.  It will likely also depend on whether you can pipeline multiple independent 2x2 matrix multiplications.

Comment: @fuz GCC seems to require at least AVX2 before it will generate SIMD instructions for 64-bit integer matrix multiplication.

Comment: @RossRidge Indeed.

Comment: It's hard to beat scalar 64-bit using multiple 32x32=>64-bit SIMD `pmuludq`.  AVX512DQ for SIMD 64-bit multiply makes it a lot more plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the bottom 64 bit of the result, things are easier. Assume *ymm0* to contain the four values of matrix A and *ymm1* the four values of matrix B, you could compute the product as follows:

```
vpermq        ymm2,ymm0,0x8D
vpermq        ymm3,ymm1,0x4E
vpermq        ymm0,ymm0,0xD8
vpclmullqlqdq xmm4,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmulhqlqdq xmm5,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmullqhqdq xmm6,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmulhqhqdq xmm7,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmullqlqdq xmm8,xmm2,xmm3
vpclmulhqlqdq xmm9,xmm2,xmm3
vpclmullqhqdq xmm10,xmm2,xmm3
vpclmulhqhqdq xmm11,xmm2,xmm3
vpunpcklqdq   xmm0,xmm4,xmm6
vpunpcklqdq   xmm1,xmm5,xmm7
vpunpcklqdq   xmm2,xmm8,xmm10
vpunpcklqdq   xmm3,xmm9,xmm11
vinserti128   ymm0,ymm0,xmm1,1
vinserti128   ymm2,ymm2,xmm3,1
vpaddq        ymm0,ymm0,ymm2
```

As a result, *ymm0* contains the four bottom 64 bit integers of the matrix product.

Comment: That looks cool but this question wasn't about carryless multiplication as far as I know

Comment: with carry follows, still coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full 128-bit results, things are slightly more complicated (again, *ymm0* = matrix A and *ymm1* = matrix B on input):

```
vpcmpeqq      ymm12,ymm12,ymm12
vpermq        ymm2,ymm0,0x8D
vpermq        ymm3,ymm1,0x4E
vpermq        ymm0,ymm0,0xD8
vpsllq        ymm12,ymm12,63
vpclmullqlqdq xmm4,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmulhqlqdq xmm5,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmullqhqdq xmm6,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmulhqhqdq xmm7,xmm0,xmm1
vpclmullqlqdq xmm8,xmm2,xmm3
vpclmulhqlqdq xmm9,xmm2,xmm3
vpclmullqhqdq xmm10,xmm2,xmm3
vpclmulhqhqdq xmm11,xmm2,xmm3
vpunpcklqdq   xmm0,xmm4,xmm5
vpunpckhqdq   xmm1,xmm4,xmm5
vpunpcklqdq   xmm2,xmm6,xmm7
vpunpckhqdq   xmm3,xmm6,xmm7
vpunpcklqdq   xmm4,xmm8,xmm9
vpunpckhqdq   xmm5,xmm8,xmm9
vpunpcklqdq   xmm6,xmm10,xmm11
vpunpckhqdq   xmm7,xmm10,xmm11
vinserti128   ymm0,ymm0,xmm2,1
vinserti128   ymm1,ymm1,xmm3,1
vinserti128   ymm2,ymm4,xmm6,1
vinserti128   ymm3,ymm5,xmm7,1
vpaddq        ymm2,ymm2,ymm0
vpaddq        ymm3,ymm3,ymm1
vpxor         ymm4,ymm12,ymm0
vpxor         ymm5,ymm12,ymm2
vpcmpgtq      ymm6,ymm4,ymm5
vpsubq        ymm3,ymm3,ymm6
vpunpcklqdq   ymm0,ymm2,ymm3
vpunpckhqdq   ymm1,ymm2,ymm3
```

then you get the four 128-bit matrix product coefficients in *ymm0* and *ymm1*.

Comment: `vpclmullqlqdq` is **carryless** multiply: xor instead of add.  But you have a mix of `vpaddq` and `vpxor` on the results.

Comment: If you were doing this with `vpmuludq`, you wouldn't need as many shuffles, but it's unlikely that this would be faster than 4x `mul` (4 uops each for port 1 and port 6 in modern Intel, fully pipelined.  https://agner.org/optimize/).  If you wanted the result in YMM regs, you could store/reload or `vmovq` + 
 shuffle.